# Difference of OpenCore and Stagefright

Tags: android, android-framework, stagefright, opencore

MY Understanding:

1)  `OpenCore` / `Stagefright` both are multimedia frameworks in Android.

2) `OpenCore` was replaced with `Stagefright`.

**What i do not understand?**

Where can i find information like which version supports which media framework?

For example: I am not sure if Jelly Bean has support for both `OpenCore` and `Stagefright`?

Kindly Help!!!.

Answer (score 2):

`OpenCore` was a multimedia framework developed by a company, Packet Video. `OpenCore` has been with Android from the first releases viz., `Cupcake` till the last release of `Froyo`.

In the later releases of `Froyo`, `Stagefright` was introduced under a build flag `BUILD_WITH_FULL_STAGEFRIGHT`. There was an additional control to enable/disable the `Stagefright` player through a system property.

Please have a look at line no. 629 of this file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.1_r2/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp

From **`GingerBread`** i.e. **Android 2.3** onwards, only `Stagefright` is present in the `AOSP` distribution. Hence, `JellyBean` also has only the `Stagefrght` player.